# Bash Linux how to create stderr, stdout and a combined log file

Tags: linux, bash

with the linux bash I have to redirect the logs of my nodejs application to stdout and stderr log file, but also create a third log file that combines both of them in one.

I have used : `node app.js 1>log/stdout.log 2>log/stderr.log`

And I've searched for some command to append for creating the log file that combines stdout.log with stderr.log in a combined.log file.

I 've tried to use `tee` command from the suggestions of others similar questions but I couldn't.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you have 3 variables: `0` which holds `stdin`, `1` which holds `stdout` and `2` which holds `stderr`, to be able to do what you suggest implies swaping the contents of the aforementioned 2 variables using a 3rd placeholder, `3` and the `tee` command:
By default `tee` only "catches" `stdout`

```
(((node app.js | tee log_stdout.txt) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee log_stderr.txt ) 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 ) > log_combined.txt 2>&1
```

Detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tee.shtml)

Comment: Good answer! side-note: You might want to run `stdbuf -eL -oL node app.js` to keep the order of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Below one worked for me -

`$ node a.js 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log ; cat stdout.log stderr.log >> all.log`

***a.js***

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

Demo `stdout` -

```
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# node a.js 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log ; cat stdout.log stderr.log >> all.log
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat stdout.log 
Hello World
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat stderr.log 
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat all.log    
Hello World
```

Demo `stderr` (make a silly mistake & see if it works with `stderr`) -

```
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# node a.js 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log ; cat stdout.log stderr.log >> all.log
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat stdout.log 
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat stderr.log 
/a.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.g('Hello World');
                                                                      ^

TypeError: console.g is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/a.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:618:3
root@a2980bfaeb16:/# cat all.log    
Hello World
/a.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.g('Hello World');
                                                                      ^

TypeError: console.g is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/a.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:618:3
```

Hope it helps!

PS - I tried to integrate redirections with pipes but no luck yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but if you run a nodejs server  and you use the ";" you're saying to cat the stderr and out after it has finished the execution (but being a server it will not stop and I need the logs during the execution), and if you use "&" saying to run in background both of the process, it executes the cat only at start up showing up only the firsts logs.
Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's true. That's why I mentioned that I was unable to integrate it with redirections and pipes. Glad to see we have a perfect answer now. Cheers !